# Accessing StreamListener headers from RequestContext or similar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, requestcontext

I have a service which calls a dozen other services. This reads from a Kafka topic using a `@StreamListener` in a controller class. For traceability purposes, the same headers(original request ID) from the Kafka message need to be forwarded to all the other services as well

Traditionally, with a `@PostMapping("/path")` or `GetMapping`, a request context is generated, and one can access the headers from anywhere using `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` and I would just pass the `HttpHeaders` object into a `RequestEntity` whenever I need to make an external call

However in a `StreamListener`, no request context is generated and trying to access the `RequestContextHolder` results in an exception

Here's an example of what I tried to do, which resulted in an exception:

```java
public class Controller {
  @Autowired Service1 service1
  @Autowired Service2 service2

  @StreamListener("stream")
  public void processMessage(Model model) {
    service1.execute(model);
    service2.execute(model);
  }
}

public class Service {
  RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public void execute(Model model){
    // Do some stuff

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().someCodeToGetHttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<Model> request = new HttpEntity(model, httpHeaders);
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
  }
}
```

My current workaround is to change the `StreamListener` to a `PostMapping` and have another `PostMapping` which calls that so a request context can be generated. Another option was to use a `ThreadLocal` but it seems just as janky

I'm aware of the `@Headers MessageHeaders` annotation to access the stream headers, however, this isn't accessible easily without passing the headers down to each and every service and would affect many unit tests

Ideally, I need a way to create my own request context (or whatever the proper terminology is) to have a place to store request scoped objects (the `HttpHeader`) or another thread safe way to have request headers passed down the stack without adding a request argument to `service.execute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution and am leaving it here for anyone else trying to achieve something similar

If your goal is to forward a bunch of headers end-to-end through REST controllers and Stream listeners, you might want to consider using [Spring Cloud Sleuth](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html)

Add it to your project through your maven or gradle configuration:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Specifically, in Spring Cloud Sleuth there is a feature to forward headers or "baggage" by setting the property `spring.sleuth.propagation-keys` in your application.properties. These key-value pairs are persisted through the entire trace, including any downstream http or stream calls which also implement the same propagation keys

If these fields need to be accessed on a code level, you can get and set them using the `ExtraFieldPropagation` static functions:

```java
ExtraFieldPropagation.set("country-code", "FO"); // Set
String countryCode = ExtraFieldPropagation.get("country-code"); // Get
```

Note that the `ExtraFieldPropagation` setter cannot set a property not present in the defined `spring.sleuth.propagation-keys` so arbitrary keys won't be accepted

You can read up on the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#prefixed-fields) for more information